# No links clickable in WebView embedded in ViewGroup if other children there

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a `RelativeLayout` that contains a `WebView` and a `ListView` (ListViewContainer is a subclass of ListView:

```
public AdListViewContainer(Context context, ServiceLookup lookup, MarketList list, Registry registry, BitmapCache bitmapCache, Utilities utilities, ActionFlipper flipper) {
    super(context);

    mScale = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    final int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    setClickable(true);
    if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        mAd = new WebView(context);
        mAd.setId(1234);
        mAd.setWebViewClient(new AdListWebClient());
        mAd.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d (TAG, "Inner Event " + event.getAction());
                return false;
            }
        });
        mAd.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

        lp.addRule(ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, 1);
        addView(mAd, lp);
    }
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    if (mAd != null) {
        lp.addRule(ALIGN_BOTTOM, mAd.getId());
    }
    mListContainer = new ListViewContainer(context, lookup, list, registry, bitmapCache, utilities, flipper);
    addView(mListContainer, lp);
}
```

The **WebView** is showing an ad generated by Adition, basically an img-tag in an a-tag.

The problem I have is that the ad can't be clicked. No touch or click events are received by the WebView. When I remove the ListView and the WebView is the only child of the ViewGroup (by removing the last addView call), the ad is clickable and everything is fine.

`ListViewContainer` is a straightforward subclass of `ListView` that contains a load of clickable LinearLayouts.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Funny enough, if I use the trackball to focus the webview manually, a click on the trackball will open the linked web page. But even when focussed, I still couldn't click on the ad with the touchscreen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. The ListView was overlapping the WebView, caused by using ALIGN_BOTTOM instead of ABOVE. D'Oh. HierarchyViewer was a blast in finding this.

Answer (score 0):

I overrode OnTouchEvent for the Webview, and put the WebView inside of a FrameLayout, filling it, then put everything else I needed on top of the webview.  Working great!